# PHP Drupal 6 XMLRPC calls

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, xml-rpc

Using XMLRPC I'm attempting to see if the node table and two custom tables contain specific values.  I'm not looking for a coding solution, just general code tips on function calls to use with parameters.

Three tables.
dp_node
dp_content_type_artists
dp_content_field_vid_url

The general logic is take a title and a artist name.  See if the combination of title (song title) and artist name exists.  If it does replace the vid_url value with the new video url otherwise insert.  Lets use Bob Dylan as the artist and Rainy Day Women as the song title.

My question is this.  Using the assumption that node.get is the right procedure to use, how would I filter to get the title from dp_node AND the artist from dp_content_type_artist.

```
  $node = 35764;
  $drupal->call('node.get',$node, array());
```

The above gets a node, I just haven't be able to figure out how to filter on title and artist name.

Answer (score 1):

`node.get` isn't the correct procedure I'm afraid, it only has the ability to return a single node. You can see this for yourself if you look in `sites/all/modules/services/node_service/node_service.module`, at the `node_service_service()` function.

There's a `search_service` module included with Services v2 (which I guess you're using as `node.get` has actually been removed from Services v3) that will allow you to do a text search for content but there's no explicit in-built functionality to get a list of nodes with a filter.

Having said that, there is a `views_service` module also included which I think is the one you should be using. I haven't used it before but I'd guess that you create a View in Drupal that filters your nodes based on your required parameters, and then call that view with those parameters from your XMLRPC client.

Hope that helps.